# Can't mount Windows partition r/w anymore

Tags: mount, microsoft-windows

After a recent crash (but recovery and correct reboot afterwards) of my Win8.1, Freya is no longer able to mount the NTFS partition. When I try that I get the error that Windows is in the suspended state (error 14), but I have shut down Windows completely. How can I mount the partition in r/w-mode again?

Edit: I can boot Windows perfectly, can reboot, and have also deactivated fastboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my own question is: I ran `chkdsk` once, and afterwards everything went back to normal, thus I assume I reset a faulty bit.

Answer (score 1):

That's the thing. Even though you *think* that you have completely shut down your Windows system, you really didn't. Windows keeps the drive mounted so it can speed up its boot process (this has nothing to do with fastboot, it's a normal Windows behavior since Windows 8).

Try turning off your Windows system by typing this into your `cmd`:

```
 shutdown -s -t 0
```

This command will shut down your Windows system completely and you will be able to use the partition from the elementary installation.

Note that the command will shut down your system immediately. To set a time interval, you can change the `0` at the end to `30`, which will shut down your system in 30 seconds. If you don't include the `-t 0` at the end of the command, I *think* that the default behavior is to set the time to 60 seconds.

As an alternative, you can mount the partition as read-only by typing this in your terminal:

```
sudo mkdir /media/Windows
sudo mount -o ro /dev/sdaX /media/Windows
```

You only have to execute the first command once.

Comment: Read only is not acceptable, I want to have r/w-access to it. The strange thing is that this only happened after a driver crash on windows.

Comment: System can be mounted only in read-only mode if it's damaged. Run chkdsk for the volume and I think it should get better.

Comment: @arc_lupus Then try the first thing I wrote and your problem should be resolved.

Comment: @V_Pavel: chkdsk solved it, even if it did not find any problems, thanks!

Comment: @arc_lupus no problem :) Apparently FS had a dirty bit set - it means "file system is in use" which is quite possible since your system crashed unexpectedly last time. Dirty bit might prevent FS from mounting in rw-mode. chkdsk removed the dirty bit, and voila. :) Glad it helped you!

Comment: @V_Pavel: The most interesting part of it is that even if I rebooted windows several times cleanly it did not change anything till I used chkdsk

Comment: @arc_lupus Please write an answer to your own question then, explain how you got it resolved and approve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the device identifier of your windows partition first find that with fdisk. It will be the large NTFS one (most likely on /dev/sda)

`sudo fdisk -l`

Then run the linux equivalent of chkdsk, replacing the XY with partition ID (eg `/dev/sda2`)

`sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY`

If that does not work try the adding the -d flag to ntfsfix to set the **dirty** flag on the partition which will force windows to run chkdsk on next boot.

`sudo ntfsfix -d /dev/sdXY`